# VS Code 1.81 unable to open git folder mounted network drive

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control

Since a few days my "git" source control within VS Code does not seem to work as intended.

Opening any existing repo I was working on previously does only return

> The folder currently open doesn't have a git repository. You can initialize a repository which will enable source control features powered by git.

Using "Initialize Repository" results in git aborting due to the "re-init".

> 2023-08-30 11:26:37.320 [info] > git init -b main [273ms]
> 2023-08-30 11:26:37.320 [info] warning: re-init: ignored --initial-branch=main

### Details:

Windows 10
VSCode 1.81.1
git 2.33

Reinstalling (and upgrading VSCode in the process) did not yield a better result.

Copying the Repository to a local directory and opening the repositroy from a local directory instead of my mapped "network-home" directory does allow vscode to enable git.

Running git itself on the mounted network drive works without an issue.

Interestingly the other tabs in the source control work. The commithistory, contributers and other tabs work, only the main source control with the changes and commit view does not work.

There are similar threads explaining it may be a folder permission issue, but in my case its not. vscode, git and the folder are all owned by me.

## Question

**Did newer VSCode versions add additional safeguards against mounted network drives?**

Comment: you're using gitlens? does VS Code's builtin stuff work okay if you disable gitlens?

Comment: @starball yes. The issue still persists while disabling all extensions. (I used vscode new Troubleshoot Issue feature.)  I am quite sure its a new safeguard against network storage. I'm just not sure where or which setting has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

This is indeed a Bug in Visual Studio Code version 1.81.

More Details in the Github Issue linked below.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190146

This is fixed in version 1.82 (August Release 2023)